# HighCharts - data from different intervals in one xAxis (hide second xAxis)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to show data from different date intervals in hour granularity in the same xAxis. I would like to show the two charts over each other, not near each other.

I can do it with 2 xAxis. See example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/X3jPh/770/

Is it possible to hide the second xAxis, because as you see in the example both has the same hour intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer here: http://dev.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=9917&p=45544

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it would make more sense to normalize that data first (i.e. adjust the values so that they happen on the same day), then display the data normally.

I do not think it is possible to plot the data in the way you intend. In order to show two different series with different start intervals with the same xAxis, you'll have to resort to some sort of trickery (since the chart is technically displaying two different dates, even if they are the same time).